# Saving result of sqlite3 package for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to save data in array from `db.get(...) => {...}`, but every time I got empty array, I don't understand it's something with scope or with method `db.get(...) => {...}`? Please help me fix this. My main goal

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./ProblemsForPatan.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);

let sql = 'SELECT * FROM Problems';

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {

  rows.forEach((rowQuestion) => {

    let arrayWithQuestionsId = _.split(rowQuestion.problem_questions_id, ',')
    
    var arrayOfAnswers = []
    arrayWithQuestionsId.forEach((id) => {

      let sql = `SELECT * FROM QuestionsAndAnswersOfProblems WHERE question_id = ?`
      
      db.get(sql, [id], (err, rowAnswer) => {
         console.log(rowAnswer) // Object
         arrayOfAnswers.push(rowAnswer)
      }) // db.get(...)
      console.log(arrayOfAnswers) // []
    }) // arrayWithQuestionsId.forEach(...)
    rowQuestion.answer = arrayOfAsnwers;
  }) // rows.forEach(...)
  console.log(rows) // [objects with 'answer': []]
}) // db.all(...)
```

What I wanna do it's get `rowQuestion` object and add `answer: [array of objects]`  field instead `rowQuestion` with `answer: [empty]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `db.get()` to fetch the answers is asynchronous which means that your `console.log(rows)` is executing before the answers have been populated. You will need to use a callback when the "rows" have finished processing.

```js
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  // track the index here with a second parameter of "index"
  rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    // loop over the problem_questions_id
    _.split(row.problem_questions_id, ',').forEach((id) => {
      let sql = `SELECT * FROM QuestionsAndAnswersOfProblems WHERE question_id = ?`;
      // use db.all not db.get to fetch an array of answers
      // this call is asynchronous so we need to check if we are done inside the callback
      db.all(sql, [id], (err, answers) => {
         // "answers" is an array here
         row.answer = answers;
         // if the index is one less than the length it's the last
         if (index === rows.length-1) {
           // we're done!
           done(rows);
         }
      });
    });
  });
});

// this is called asynchronously when all the answers have been fetched
function done(rows) {
  console.log(rows);
}
```